# tfs2010 selenium - Unit testing against a previous build

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration

I use Selenium 2 (i.e. web driver) for unit testing in VS2010/TFS2010 environment. When the build (call it build # n) is triggered via checkin, the unit tests run (including Selenium ones) and after passing, the new site is published. As you can see, I just ran Selenium tests against an old web site (from build n-1).

So the question is, how do I make sure that Selenium tests run against the latest site. I kind of want the deploy/publish to happen before running Selenium tests. Is that possible? Also, what if Selenium tests fails - deploy would have to be reverted back.

Answer (score 0):

Your build should deploy to localhost / other dev site first and run the tests, then if they pass, deploy to the production site.

Comment: To clarify, at the moment there is no production site. I check in code, build gets triggered on the build server (tests run as part of it) and finally if everything is OK, deploy happens on the build server. So once deployed, I guess I need to run Selenium tests again to make sure they run against the latest site?

Comment: Your unit tests aren't really unit tests, because they require the application to be deployed. They should be called integration tests. They should always run *after* the application is deployed.

Comment: My bad, yes Selenium tests are integration tests - I am running them along with other genuine unit tests. So once these unit tests are run and application is deployed on the build server, Selenium tests should run. Question then is, how do I automate running Selenium tests after the deployment (in TFS2010). Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Yeah, I'm used to Maven (a Java thing) which has two separate test phases, but I don't know how to do it with your stack.

Comment: Looks like I have to buy the Ultimate Edition of VS2010 with the Lab Manager which allows me to write "coded-ui" (Selenium type) tests. Does not appear to be possible in VS2010 alone unless someone knows better.